# "To the East/West/North/South are distinct [feature-rich] areas that fill the land"

Tags: grammar, translation

Could I check my understanding of the last part of this sentence please? For those who don't play games, Hyrule is a fictional place in the Legend of Zelda videogames (this is from a guidebook I am translating).

I think I have the meaning, but the words look strange to me. "there are features area being spread out Hyrule".
I'd like some clarification as to whether some particles have been dropped here, or if I am misunderstanding this part of the sentence.

> 森、平原、峡谷、湖・・・。ハイラル城と城下町を中心に、東西南北へ特徴あるエリアが広がるハイラル。
>   Forests, plaines, canyons, lakes... Hyrule Castle and centrally the castle town, to the East/West/North/South are distinct [feature-rich] areas that fill Hyrule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of it as "in all directions of the compass".

Comment: I think this is the key to understanding it. It does not mean to the north is X, to the south is Y, it just means that around you are these things. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain it in English, but I can show the meaning of your sentence by drawing this figure:

[image]

Comment: Nice picture, but logically you cannot infer that 東西南北 maps directly to the order of the 森、平原、峡谷、湖 from the way it is written (which you have wrong anyway).